# using particular default parameters for a func

Tags: c++

If I am having the following function defination. On calling I wish pass values just for a and c and use the default value for b how will I call this function

```
void func(int a=5,int b=2, int c=3)
{
..........
.........
}
```

Comment: Overload? `void func(int a, int c) { func(a,2,c); }`?

Comment: the thing is I am doing this for a library and this function is inside a class. So the user using it wont actualy know the default values. So is there anyway I could do that without specifying the default value. Is there something possible like func(2,,3). I tried func(2,,3) but the compiler gives error

Comment: you should order the parameters in a way which makes sense; most likely to be left as default on the right. If that's not possible in this case, then go with Daniel's solution (but obviously that wouldn't work in an ambiguous case like this example, where everything is an `int`)

Comment: reordering the parameters wont help. For example if i wana use default values of a and c and specify value for b then????

Comment: you want the user not to specify the second parameter and actually know what’s the default parameter but he doesn’t know default value because he won’t pass it anyway. Wait, whaaaaat?!

Comment: C/C++ doesn't support named parameters like python or other languages, i.e. result = func(a=1, c=2);

Comment: @dutt: Not by default, but there is a library [Boost Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#parameter-enabled-functions)

Comment: @dutt, that’s obvious, you always have to specify all parameters in C++, there’s no laziness over them nor variadic expansion by default

Comment: @skp: For somebody new to the language it might not be so obvious, hence I thought to clarify that for the OP.

Comment: @skp i never said user knows the value of default parameter. I said he just wana use the one which was provided by developer. Maybe to test the library or sumthing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not support the following kind of syntax:

```
func(1, , 2);
```

This means that only the right-most parameters that you omit can take default values.

If you want to be able to have default parameters in arbitrary combinations, you could consider using [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::optional<int> OptionalInt;
typedef boost::optional<int> Default;

void func(OptionalInt a, OptionalInt b, OptionalInt c)
{
   if (!a) a = 5;
   if (!b) b = 2;
   if (!c) c = 3;
   std::cout << *a << std::endl;
   std::cout << *b << std::endl;
   std::cout << *c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   func(1, Default(), 1);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: omg that’s terribly stupid. I mean, the idea of `boost::optional` is not worth it. Just pass a pointer and make a macro like

`#define DEF 0`

Comment: @skp i didnt get you could u please a bit more specific

Comment: @skp Fair enough, but this is stackoverflow, and you should generally explain why, if you disagree with something (otherwise other people reading it won't know what your reasoning was).

Comment: well, `optional<int>()` is quite long, and will result in a type that will be checked at runtime. It’s actually the same thing with a pointer, but faster.

Comment: @skp well, you can typedef, so the first point shouldn't matter. Can you elaborate on the pointer thing?

Comment: Edited with `typedef`s to make it more readable, and converted it into a compilable example.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ 11 standard (N3485): 8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default]

> For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the same scope.
>   Examples from the standards:
>
> void f(int, int)
>
> void f(int, int = 7); //OK

So the rule is that you have to specify default arguments from the right to the left of the parameter list. You cannot only specify default value to `a` without specifying the `b` and `c` before that:

```
void func(int a = 10, int b, int c); //ERROR
```

However,you may try the following:

```
void func(int a,int b, int c=3); //set default for c at first
void func(int a,int b = 5, int c);  //at later declarations, set for b
void func(int a =10, int b, int c);//at even later declarations, set for a
```

With the above, you can call the function as follows:

```
func(20); //call use default value of b and c
func(15,20); //call use default value of c
func(10,20,30); //do not use default value
func(); // use default values for a, b and c
```

So you can use default values of `b` and `c` at the same time as you like, or use `c` only, but you cannot call `func` by using default value of `b` only since it is the middle of the parameter list, similarly, you cannot call `func` using default value of `a` only. This way, you only add declarations and do not have redundant code. However, you can not really call them such that they can use default values in arbitrary way.

You can find a live example here [default arguments example](http://ideone.com/IC9eiY#view_edit_box)

Comment: that wont help as for sum calls I would also need to to use default value of a and pass b and c. I dont wana write redundant code.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh does this works better for you? Though it does not really do all you want, but I think it is much better to change the declaration order of parameter lists.

Comment: yup it atleast clears all my doubts very well...thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion: [Boost Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#parameter-enabled-functions)

```
#include <boost/parameter/name.hpp>
#include <boost/parameter/preprocessor.hpp>

BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(a)    
BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(b)
BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(c)

BOOST_PARAMETER_FUNCTION((void),
                         func,
                         tag,
                         (optional            
                          (a, *, 5)
                          (b, *, 2)
                          (c, *, 3)))
{
}
int main()
{
    func(_a = 5, _c = 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for you.

Option 1: Pass a dictionary-like object:

```
struct myParameters {
    int a,b,c;
    myParameters( ) : a(3), b(4), c(5) {}
}
void myFunction( const myParameters &p ) {
    int a = p.a;
    int b = p.b;
    int c = p.c;
    // stuff
}

myParameters t;
t.a = 3;
t.c = 7;
myFunction( myParameters );
```

Option 2: Use otherwise nonsensical values to denote defaults:

```
#define DEFAULT -1;
void myFunction( int a = DEFAULT, int b = DEFAULT, int c = DEFAULT ) {
    if( a == DEFAULT ) { a = 3; }
    if( b == DEFAULT ) { b = 4; }
    if( c == DEFAULT ) { c = 5; }
    // stuff
}
```

(but of course you can't pass `-1` as an actual value; you could use `INT_MAX` or something else too)

Option 3: Use overloading and an enum (could get messy):

```
enum NoVal {
DEFAULT
};
void myFunction( int a = 3, int b = 4, int c = 5 ) {
    // stuff
}
void myFunction( int a = 3, NoVal, int c = 5 ) {
    return myFunction( a, 4, c );
}
void myFunction( NoVal, int b = 4, int c = 5 ) {
    return myFunction( 3, b, c );
}
void myFunction( NoVal, NoVal, int c = 5 ) {
    return myFunction( 3, 4, c );
}

myFunction( 10, DEFAULT, 2 );
```

Option 4: Adjust your function so that the parameters are in a more logical order.

Comment: could you please explain how to call the func using option 2

Comment: The problem with using nonsensical values is that you don't always have one available i.e. if any value is a valid one. In fact this is one of the main reasons boost::optional was created (see my answer for a solution which uses that). However, it's fine if you do have invalid values available e.g. where you're using `int` and are never going to pass negative values.

Comment: Option 2 is called the same way as option 3. And @JBentley, I mentioned that below the example. Boost's implementation is essentially just a wrapper object, so it's the same as skp's answer (with the code fixed as in my comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like that

```
#define DEF 0
void func(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  if (a) *a = 5;
  if (b) *b = 2;
  if (c) *c = 3;
}
```

And call it that way:

```
int x = 9;
int y = 10;
func(&x, DEF, &y);
```

Comment: SEGFAULT ahoy! You can't assign `*a` if `a` is `NULL`! But the idea is sound.

Comment: hmm, your code has changed, but now there's a new problem; you only set the default value when the user passed a variable. If they passed `DEF` it doesn't set the default.

Comment: it’s an example of interface. I think he’s smart enough to adapt.

Comment: No I mean this code actually won't work. Inside your function you need to do something like `int aa = a ? (*a) : 5`.